# Not to commit previous commits, I want just to add a commit that takes all the other changes made on the other branch I merged?

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit

I want to get the changes but not to publish all those commits that I did on the test branch ... What I want is that after merging, taking those changes and committing (once) on the master, not to publish all those commits.

Thanks

I haven't tried anything because I want to be sure about what to do. Then I will push again.

```
git merge test
git status
```

Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 6 commits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could squash your commits, but I tend to prefer the simplicity of recommitting. I post the solution here for those interested :

```
git checkout test
git reset --soft origin/master
git commit -m "message for this whole feature"
git push origin HEAD
```

Then the `test-branch` will be pushed to the remote, and your merge request `test > master` will feature only the one commit made above.

Comment: Wasn't it going to affect the commits made by my partners before on the master branch? thx Because the master branch has some changes other people has commited. Please answer so I could try what you told me to

Comment: When I did "git reset --soft origin/master" I got the changes uncommitted, even they seem to be green, which means I haven't added them or something like that ... Is that normal?

Comment: @ReynaldRamirezdeLuna The `--soft` flag, contrary to `--mixed` which is the default mode, keeps changes in the index (added, staged, cached, whatever you're used to call it). Where do you see this "in green"? In command line, when you do a `git status -sb` your changed files should appear with a green letter (staged changes) in front of them rather than red one (unstaged changes).

Comment: @ReynaldRamirezdeLuna ...and about your first comment (sorry, didn't see it earlier), changes that are gonna be regrouped are whatever is on your local master but not on remote. Isn't it what you wanted to do? Do other people commit from your local?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But my question was if the git history log will be overwritten or something like that (the remote one). The thing is that I've never used "git push origin HEAD" before...

Comment: No, the (past) remote history won't change since you're building on top of it (`origin/master` is where it points for now). It will only change in the sense of "being added to".

Comment: Thnx! Let's rock!!

Comment: @ReynaldRamirezdeLuna Btw, as a last call before you push, feel free to inspect the log of what you're about to push, and do only if it satisfies your expectations.

Comment: Amm.. It's just by git log, right? It will show me what it's about to be pushed

Comment: @ReynaldRamirezdeLuna Without any parameters, it will show you all history but will be slightly inconvenient to read, maybe. Try `git log origin/master..` (mind the dots) to focus on the interesting part, and use whatever formatting option you need to output the info which is the most relevant to you ([pretty formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats)).

Answer (score 1):

```
git merge test --squash
git commit -m "foo bar"
```

With `--squash`, changes are merged and commits are not.